# Laravel Relationship error

Tags: laravel

i have a problem in getting the data of my db.
I have two models User, Follower.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Follower extends Model

        {
            public function mentor()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','mentor_id');
            }
            public function follower()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');
            }
        }

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Friend;
use App\Follower;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
public function followers()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Follower','mentor_id','id');
   }

   public function follows()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Follower','user_id','id');
   }
}
```

**Database 'followers'**

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFollowerTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('mentor_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('followers');

    }
}
```

I'm getting the data through my FollowerController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Follower;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
class FollowerController extends Controller
{
    public function getFollows(Request $request)
    {
        $follows=Auth::user()->follows()->get();
        return view('follows',['follows' => $follows]);
    }
    public function getFollowers(Request $request)
    {
        $followers=Auth::user()->followers()->get();
        return view('followers',['followers' => $followers]);
    }
}
```

And here i'm getting such error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNxgm.png)

I don't know why but it adds in SQL request that 'users.'
I ll be very pleasant if u help me

Comment: you don't have `mentor_id`(foreign key) in users table. define it first

Comment: `Schema::create('follows.blade.php', function (Blueprint $table)` what?

Comment: ok fail wait a sec ill correct

Comment: Ok, i changed but it doesn't work, anyway the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're complicating this. All you need is a pivot table to hold the followers information.

Add the `follows` pivot table

```
Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('follower_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('followed_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->primary(['follower_id', 'followed_id']);

    $table->foreign('follower_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('followed_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Add this to `User` model.

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followed_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'followed_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In your controller do this.

```
public function getFollows()
{
    $follows = auth()->user()->following;
    return view('follows', ['follows' => $follows]);
}

public function getFollowers()
{
    $followers = auth()->user()->followers;
    return view('followers', ['followers' => $followers]);
}
```

I based the code of the follow feature implemented in one of my OSS projects. You can check it out to learn more.

https://github.com/gothinkster/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/master/database/migrations/2017_04_27_200850_create_follows_table.php

https://github.com/gothinkster/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/master/app/RealWorld/Follow/Followable.php

Note : You don't need to define a model for the pivot table. You're getting both the follower and following information from the User model relationship.